# How to make a CCTextFieldTTF move up when keyboard is present: Cocos2d-x

Tags: cocos2d-x

I want to CCTextFieldTTF move up when keyboard is present, it hides behind keyboard and user not able to see what he type.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: I'd create a native function in your backend, which tells game that keyboard has opened or close (not sure if it's somewhere implemented already). Then you can temponary move your sprite up.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set CCTextFieldTTF's position when keyboard is present. Do it in its TextFieldDelegate function:

```
virtual bool onTextFieldAttachWithIME(TextFieldTTF * sender);
```

this function will be called when keyboard shows up. However, I think the better way is to set
CCTextFieldTTF as a password text by:

```
textField.setSecureTextEntry(true);
```